# Powershell [System.Windows.Forms.SendKey], ALT don't work properly

Tags: vba, powershell, sendkeys, citrix

I have powershell script that automate some tasks I am doing.
We are using Citrix and in order to get to an app in Citrix I am using Selenium.
The main problem in Citrix is that I can only use SendKeys to automate within the app after Selenium clicked it because I actually see a "Remote" UI.

My Code:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait(" ") ## Space to focus on item
Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{ENTER}") ## Enter to get into Printer Settings UI
Start-Sleep -Seconds 2
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("%") ## ALT to focus on the menu
Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{ENTER}") ## Enter to open the menu
```

I am loading System.Windows.Forms with Add-Type,
and using [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait() to SendKeys.

I am using "Space" (" ") to focus and "{Enter}" to enter Settings UI, that's working..
But within the new settings UI window I can't seems to press "ALT" using the SendKeys to navigate to the menu and open it.

What weird about this problem is:

1. The window that opened the settings UI react properly to the SendKeys.
2. When I am not using SendKeys within the settings UI, but rather I click the ALT on the keyboard, the settings UI reacts properly to me smashing my keyboard...
3. The ALT sendkey works, because the ALT reacts fine when on Notepad or other application.

Thanks!

I tried to use VBA AppActivate, no success.

Comment: FYI, SO has rules: [Provide MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) --- [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) --- [Don't ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) --- [Proper Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) --- [Why not upload images of code/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) --- [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) --- [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Of course SendKeys has been around long before PS ever existed and there are tons of resources to show you what you use in the old (VBS) way and the new way (PS).  SK, is really finicky and often will not do as you asked, well, not without going the extra distance. If you cannot focus on the GUI (form, dialog, etc), then SK is moot. You are not showing any code you are using, and that is a SO rule. UNless a person has your environment to test against, then, well, there is no way to validate what you are saying/require. So, again, post code, no screen shots of code, or a pointer to other detail

Comment: @postanote hey, I added a code sample. I can't focus on a window, since Citrix is render remote application from remote servers. But I can wait for the app to show, and then it focused because it was just opened and first in line. the Space and Enter works. Then a new UI being opened, and there I want to hit ALT for menu. but It seems no Special Keys work. for exmaple - where the Enter and Space is working, sending Shift+F10 ("+{F10}") doesn't work. neither TAB (%). but ENTER and Space is working.
Standing on the UI and press the Keyboard manually seems to work, so my question is why ?

Comment: Again, I don't have a Citrix environment to see what you are saying. So, you can set up a Github or similar report to post a video of what you are seeing., Yet again, SK, is very finicky and timing moves from X to Y can be a headache and will vary between host(s) where this would be executed. SK is really not 100% thing. It can take a lot of gymnastics for come use cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem using [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys] class with Citrix, because Citrix terminal server can't handle special tabs using the SendKeys.
The solution is to download AutoIT and take out the .dll files (3 files).
Then load it to your C# code or to the Powershell and use it.
AutoIT sendkeys seems to interact just fine with citrix terminal servers and your automation can work fine with the sendkeys.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).